# InvalidClassException when running application on a different computer

Tags: java, swing

This occur after I open my project in another computer and after log in screen this error came up.
 I include all the libraries I used to create this in my desktop computer, where it works fine.
 I can't find the error and fix it

This is the code from lines 180 to 185, referenced in the error:

```
CB_vendor(javax.swing.JComboBox)java.beans.Beans.instantiate(getClass().getClassLoader(), "newproject.NewJFrame_CB_vendor");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} ##
```

After I import my project to NetBeans I run it in the normal way: `project ---right click -----run`

The full error:

> ```
> java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComboBox; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1692960661481242205, local class serialVersionUID = 8351908727136020938
>     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:199)
>     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
>     at newproject.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:180)
>     at newproject.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:48)
>     at newproject.logIn.jButton1ActionPerformed(logIn.java:241)
>     at newproject.logIn.access$300(logIn.java:26)
>     at newproject.logIn$4.actionPerformed(logIn.java:118)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComboBox; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1692960661481242205, local class serialVersionUID = 8351908727136020938
>     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:199)
>     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
>     at newproject.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:209)
>     at newproject.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:48)
>     at newproject.logIn.jButton1ActionPerformed(logIn.java:241)
>     at newproject.logIn.access$300(logIn.java:26)
>     at newproject.logIn$4.actionPerformed(logIn.java:118)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
> ```

Comment: What's going on on line 180 of the NewJFrame class: `NewJFrame.java:180`? The exception message is telling you that this is the location of your problem.

Comment: You should avoid posting code in comments since it loses its formatting, and instead post it as an [edit to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26447262/edit). Tell us how you're trying to run your program. Are you running it as a jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have serialized a JComboBox but the serialVersionUID doesn't match between the class the runtime knows about and the class that was serialized.  If you look at the [Javadoc for the Serializable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), it explains how that field is used to make sure the serialized version and what the JVM wants to create from the serialized object are the same.

Since that class is part of the Java standard library, I would suggest that you ran code that serialized a JComboBox on one version of the JVM and are trying to deserialize it on another.

As a side note, it is rarely appropriate to serialize a UI element like a JComboBox.  Usually you want to serialize data, not whatever is showing that data (so you save the state of the JComboBox -- what is selected -- and then restore that into a new JComboBox).  That way you don't run into problems like this.

Answer (score 5):

You've serialized a `JComboBox` across JRE versions. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html):

> Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing.